# Cucumber without Maven

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

We are not Maven yet, and I’m trying to run a cucumber feature. Getting the below error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.picocontainer.PicoBuilder at
>   cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.start(PicoFactory.java:17)

Below is my folder structure for src.

```html
src
   test.java.stepdefinition.holiday
       Myholiday_StepDef.java
       MyRunner.java
   test.resources.features
       holiday.feature
```

Comment: Have u included cucumber-picocontainer in the classpath?

Comment: Yes- I did. But code worked when I added pico container in addition to cucumber-picocontainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  Jar file of  “PicoContainer Core” to build path of your project if you are using java project.

You can use maven dependency for “PicoContainer  Core” to your pom.xml (for Maven project) as mentioned below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
    <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```